# On Microphone permission in iOS 16 producing screeching noise

Tags: ios, objective-c, microphone, audiokit, ios16

I am working on a guitar application written in Objective-C. It has a feature like Tuning from Guitar. The tuning screen requires microphone permission. When we give permission to the app, suddenly the app starts producing a screeching noise which sounds very weird.

The same code is working on iOS 15 and lower versions. Only in iOS 16 and higher it is having this noise issue.

I have used audiokit and the version of audiokit is 2.2 and the latest version is 5.5.7

`pod 'AudioKit'`

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Without some code, it's hard to tell what could possible be happening. You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74318001/edit) your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to make the question on-topic. At least show your audio render callback and how you're processing microphone/audio data.

Answer (score 1):

The screeching noise is because there is a feedback loop between your microphone and speaker. You could set the `AVAudioSession.Category` to `.record` which would silence the playback audio. If you need to use a `.playAndRecord` session then you need to make sure the output node for your `AVAudioSession` instance is silent.

Comment: Thank you brother. I will try your suggestion and will get back to you.

Comment: I tried your solution but still having same noice issue coming.

Comment: how do you do this? I did  engine.output?.bypass() and still heard the noise bleeding

Answer (score 0):

There are a few examples in the AudioKit Cookbook that show how to access the mic muted in AudioKit 5. https://github.com/AudioKit/Cookbook/blob/main/Cookbook/CookbookCommon/Sources/CookbookCommon/Recipes/MiniApps/Recorder.swift